# which is the best way to implement React router modal that allows navigation inside the own modal

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm following this code, which allow use some routes inside your modal, this works ok although the code is a bit unclear to me,

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery

basically I understand that before clicking in some modal link we save the location, also we toggle some backgroud state which allow to our routes know that the modal must be displayed, our routes then get the previous route and render that component (which would be the page where the link to our modal live) and render the modal (because the background state is not null)

so far so good, but now I need move between modals, basically I need display some modal with different links inside it (pointing to another modal) and when the user click some link keep the modal open and display the new content

not sure how create a fork from this code
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery

but you can replace the code inside that windows with it and get the idea

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useHistory,
  useLocation,
} from 'react-router-dom';

// This example shows how to render two different screens
// (or the same screen in a different context) at the same URL,
// depending on how you got there.
//
// Click the "featured images" and see them full screen. Then
// "visit the gallery" and click on the colors. Note the URL and
// the component are the same as before but now we see them
// inside a modal on top of the gallery screen.

export default function ModalGalleryExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ModalSwitch />
    </Router>
  );
}

function ModalSwitch() {
  const location = useLocation();

  // This piece of state is set when one of the
  // gallery links is clicked. The `background` state
  // is the location that we were at when one of
  // the gallery links was clicked. If it's there,
  // use it as the location for the <Switch> so
  // we show the gallery in the background, behind
  // the modal.
  const background = location.state && location.state.background;
  console.log('brackground is', background);
  console.log('background is ', background);
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch location={background || location}>
        <Route path="/" children={<Gallery />} />
      </Switch>

      {/* Show the modal when a background page is set */}

      {background && <Route path="/modal1" children={Modal1(Hello)} />}
      {background && <Route path="/modal2" children={Modal1(Bye)} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function Gallery() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log('location inside Gallery ', location);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: '/modal1',
            // This is the trick! This link sets
            // the `background` in location state.
            state: { background: location },
          }}
        >
          hello Modal
        </Link>

        <div>
          <Link
            to={{
              pathname: '/modal2',
              // This is the trick! This link sets
              // the `background` in location state.
              state: { background: location },
            }}
          >
            bye Modal
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Hello() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log('location inside hello ', location);
  return (
    <>
      <div>Hola</div>
      <div>
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: '/modal2',
            // This is the trick! This link sets
            // the `background` in location state.
            state: { background: location },
          }}
        >
          GO TO MODAL 2
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function Bye() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log('location inside bye ', location);
  return (
    <>
      <div>Modal2: Bye</div>
      <div>
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: '/modal1',
            // This is the trick! This link sets
            // the `background` in location state.
            state: { background: location },
          }}
        >
          GO TO MODAL 1
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function Modal1(component) {
  const history = useHistory();

  const back = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    history.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <div
      onClick={back}
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)',
      }}
    >
      <div
        className="modal"
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          background: '#fff',
          top: 25,
          left: '10%',
          right: '10%',
          padding: 15,
          border: '2px solid #444',
        }}
      >
        rendered
        {component()}
        <button type="button" onClick={back}>
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

right now my possible solution is use redux and save the current page in the state, when the user moves through the modals keep that state intact so I keep displaying the background component, and the link must be the modal link...but I'd like to know if is there some great solution using plain hooks and that doesnt require redux?...thank you

NOTE: please let me know if there is a more clear question title and I'll change this
thank you so much